# How do I retrieve data to modelForm using Ajax in Django

Tags: django

I want to retrieve data to modelForm based on user input. I am developing a transaction app, I want to retrieve account balance to the form based on the account number selected by the user. First I want to print an alert to test the existence of the account number but keep getting 500 internal server error.

Here is the code

**models.py**

```
class Account(models.Model):
    ACCOUNT_TYPE = (
        ('Checking','Checking'),
        ('Savings','Savings'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE, default='select')
    account_balance = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def validate_account_number(request):
    account_number = request.Get.get['account_number']
    data = {
        'is_exist': Account.objects.filter(
            account_number=account_number).exists()
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**transaction.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method=POST id="sendform">
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active show" transfer="home">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="tile">
                <h3 class="tile-title">Transfer Money</h3>
                <div class="tile-body">

                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% bootstrap_form form%}
                    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                    <div class="tile-footer">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
                          <button type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg 
    fa-check-circle"></i>Send</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn- 
   secondary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-times-circle"> 
   </i>Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div></div>
          </div>


    </form>
    </main>
    {% endblock %}
    {% block javascript %}
    <script>
        $("#id_creditor_account").change(function(){
        var account_number = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
          url: '{% url 'users:validate_account_number'%}',
          data:{
            'account_number':account_number
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){
            if (data.is_exist){
              alert("Account exist");
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Here is the screenshot: [html_transction_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBm6C.png)

**Error from console**

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/ajax/validate_account_number/?account_number=5645786809 500 (Internal Server Error)
send    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @   (index):265
dispatch    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
ListPicker._handleMouseUp
```

Answer (score 2):

The attribute is `request.GET`, not `request.Get`. And as Ralf says, it is a method. So either:

```
account_number = request.GET.get('account_number')
```

or

```
account_number = request.GET['account_number']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in your view: the method `GET.get` cannot be indexed, but it can be called.

Try changing

```
# with brackets, capitalized 'Get'
account_number = request.Get.get['account_number']
```

to

```
# with parenthesis, all uppercase 'GET'
account_number = request.GET.get('account_number')
```

---

EDIT

Ah, right, its `request.GET` (all uppercase), not `request.Get` (capitalized).

Comment: Thanks @ralf 
account_number = request.Get.get('account_number')
still give the error

Comment: jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/ajax/validate_account_number/?account_number=5645786809 500 (Internal Server Error)